How to create a Python type alias for a parametrized type
jaxtyping provides type annotations that use a str as parameter (as opposed to a type), e.g.:
Float[Array, "dim1 dim2"]

Let's say I would like to create a type alias which combines the Float and Array part.
This means I would like to be able to write
MyOwnType["dim1 dim2"]

instead.
To my understanding I cannot use TypeAlias/TypeVar, as the generic parameter (here "dim1 dim2") is not a type but actually an instance of a type.
Is there a concise Pythonic way to achieve this?
EDIT:
I tried the following and it does not work:
class _Singleton:

    def __getitem__(self, shape: str) -> Float:
        return Float[Array, shape]

MyOwnType = _Singleton()

Using MyOwnType["dim1 dim2"]as function parameter annotation gives the mypy complaint Variable "MyOwnType" is not valid as a type
Solution:
Based on the answer of @chepner this was the final solution:
class MyOwnType(Generic[Shape]):
    def __class_getitem__(cls, shape: str) -> Float:
        return Float[Array, shape]


The method to override is __class_getitem__, not __getitem__.

You need to override/define __class_getitem__, not __getitem__ (which applies to instances of _Singleton, not _Singleton itself).
class _Singleton:

    def __class_getitem__(self, shape: str) -> Float:
        return Float[Array, shape]


Furthermore I needed the class inherit from Generic, otherwise mypy would complain about the "dim1 dim2". I added my final solution to the question.
